# Directive to format text to be displayed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am playing with [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) `directive`. I want to format the data which is going to be displayed. This is what I am doing:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input ng-model="data" type="text" test />
  <input type="button" ng-click="change()" value="Change"> {{data}}
  <br>Hello <span ng-bind="data" test></span>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = 'yellow';
    $scope.change = function() {
      $scope.data = 'black';
    };
  })
  .directive('test', function() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
          //formats the value for display when ng-model is changed
          return 'brown';
        });
        ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
          //formats the value for ng-model when input value is changed
          return 'green';
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

I am able to format the data for the model and display it for `input` text. But I am not able to format the data for the `span` which is bound to a model. `span` is showing the model as it is. I don't know why the span is showing the value of the model. I want to show the formatted value to the span as well. Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hitesh_kumar/9kxmjsnz/).

Comment: I think that it's because you don't have ng-model on span, ng-model can be used only for input elements. If you want to format text use filters `<span>{{data|test}}</span>`

Comment: @jcubic I am new to angular js. Can you please help me with a fiddle.

Comment: Maybe something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9kxmjsnz/3/

Comment: @jcubic Got it. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-model for only `input`. If you want to change a text in a div,span,label or any other element without input you can use seperators . `{}`

When you create a variable in $scope you can show it in your html.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input ng-model="data" type="text" test />
  <input type="button" ng-click="change()" value="Change"> {{data}}
  <br>Hello <span test>{data}</span>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9kxmjsnz/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is working perfectly fine only thing is you are not taking the right example here.

First of all please read below:

1. Formatters change how model values will appear in the view.
2. Parsers change how view values will be saved in the model.

and now replace the code below

```
ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
          //formats the value for display when ng-model is changed
          return 'brown';
        });
        ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
          //formats the value for ng-model when input value is changed
          return 'green';
        });
```

with

```
ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
          //formats the value for display when ng-model is changed
          return value.toLowerCase();
        });
        ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
          //formats the value for ng-model when input value is changed
          return value.toUpperCase();
        });
```

I hope this help!!